# Как правильно заменить цикл for на stream в данном коде

Tags: java, циклы, потоки-данных, java-stream

Мне нужно переписать цикл в методе `convertArrayToMapWithKeysAndValues` через `stream`, но не понимаю как правильно это сделать.

```
private static String[] keysAndValuesList = new String[] {
        "-i", "in.txt", "--limit", "40", "-d", "1", "-o", "out.txt"
};

public static Map<String, String> convertArrayToMapWithKeysAndValues() {
    Map<String, String> convertArray = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < keysAndValuesList.length;) {
        convertArray.put(keysAndValuesList[i], keysAndValuesList[i + 1]);
        i += 2;
    }
    return convertArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
public static Map<String, String> convertArrayToMapWithKeysAndValues() {
    return IntStream.range(0, keysAndValuesList.length / 2)
            .boxed()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            i -> keysAndValuesList[i * 2],
                            i -> keysAndValuesList[i * 2 + 1]));
}
```

Comment: А для чего мы делим на 2 ?

Comment: @Tokamo Для того чтобы разбить на пары. В примере у Вас массив состоящий из 8 элементов, т.е. 4 пары (8 / 2 = 4)

Comment: @Tokamo Нет. Код корректен. Мы получим 4 числа - 0, 1, 2, 3. В случае, если мы бы сделали включительно, то было бы еще число 4 и мы бы получили индексы 8 и 9, которых не существует.

Comment: А, я понял, благодарю